# AWS neptune throwing timeout error when th e query timeout value is higher

Tags: amazon-web-services, gremlin, amazon-neptune, gremlinpython

I am running a gremlin query on the AWS neptune which use to take 2.5 minutes for the results,
I have kept my  `neptune_query_timeout = 500000` , the neptune engine version is 1.0.4.1

Recently I am seeing this error on my same query which just use to work fine earlier-

```
{'error': TimeoutError('Operation timed out after 30 seconds',)}
```

It doesn't look to me that actual query on neptune is timing out, i have kept a long timeout of 500000 in the config file already and it use to work fine before.

Recently i am seeing the above error and have no idea how to overcome this.

---

EDITED

The graph looks like

Users (node) ---- played(edge)-----> games(node)

So the actual query i am trying to run is this-

```
g.V().hasLabel('users').where(outE('played').count().is(gt(10)))
```

which runs fine and gives me all the users who played more than 10 times or in other words had 10 or more "played" edges from the users node.

but when i just want the count of users and modified the query as below I am hitting the timeout error.

```
g.V().hasLabel('transient_id').where(outE('visited').count().is(gt(10))).count().next()
```

Any help is appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Can you run the query through the Neptune Gremlin Profiler and post the output here?  Not the profile() step, but this:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/gremlin-profile-api.html  You can also get to this via `%%gremlin profile` in the Neptune Notebooks.

Comment: Are you using custom-endpoints?  If yes, do you mind trying with the default db cluster endpoint instead?

Comment: Also, if you're using TornadoTransport in the client, make sure you don't use the default timeout: https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/master/gremlin-python/src/main/python/gremlin_python/driver/tornado/transport.py#L29

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue in the 3.4.9 version of the Apache TinkerPop Gremlin Python client that caused any query to time out (client side) at 30 seconds. From the tags on the question it looks like you are using Gremlin Python. That issue is now resolved in the 3.4.10 release from Apache TinkerPop.